# is that possible to get id populated automatically based on name in data import wizard?

Tags: data-loader, data-import-wizard

I have excel sheet with the lookup name than id and value

ID - value

1     xxx

2     yyy

object 1

LookupId - 1   value = 2

My excel sheet data upload format is

value - value

xxx       2

will it take the lookup id automatically while upload using data import ? is it possible ?

Comment: The data import wizard does allow matching lookups based on names rather than Id, you just have to be consistent in the data in the import file so you can't mix names and Salesforce Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible for the data import wizard to match on names in Lookup fields, you will get the option to select which of them you are using when you select the object that you are loading.

[image]

[Tipsheet link](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_import_wizard_tipsheet.pdf)

[Choosing which tool](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=import_which_data_import_tool.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.6)

[Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/load_data_intro.htm)